# How to visualize code coverage information on Go GAE apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, unit-testing, go, tdd, code-coverage

I am developing a server with the [latest](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForGoReleaseNotes) [Go GAE SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/). I am running tests after every change:

```
goapp test -test.v=true
```

I am using `-cover` to record coverage as described by `goapp help testflag`:

```
goapp test -cover -test.v=true -test.coverprofile=c.out
[..]
coverage: 53.8% of statements
ok      _/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/loyalty/workspace    30.464s
```

This completes successfully and prints the percentage of lines covered by tests. However, **attempting to visualize the results fails**:

```
goapp tool cover -html=c.out
cover: can't find "app.go": cannot find package "_/home/ingo/git/loyalty/" in any of:
/home/ingo/Downloads/go_appengine_sdk_linux_amd64-1.9.10/go_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/_/home/ingo/git/loyalty (from $GOROOT)
/home/ingo/git/loyalty/src/_/home/ingo/git/loyalty (from $GOPATH)
```

Does Go's cover tool only work on non-GAE apps? Do I have to package my app differently in order to visualize the coverage results?

I unsuccessfully asked this [on golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/9UswOWUvktw/discussion) before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10749) related to it. As a temporary workaround, I am running sed in between collecting and visualizing the coverage results.

```
goapp test -cover -test.v=true -test.coverprofile=c.out
sed -i -e "s#.*/\(.*\.go\)#\./\\1#" c.out
goapp tool cover -html c.out -o coverage.html
```